# generating solvable puzzles for a Double-Choco puzzle game. efficient data structure and algorithm to be used in?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, graph-theory, puzzle

I'm working on implementing a puzzle board game called [Double-Choco](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/double_choco/) published by Nikoli magazine

Where the board is a 2-dimensional matrix with cells that are either white or gray. The goal is to divide the grid into blocks by drawing solid lines over the dotted lines. Each block must contain a pair of areas of white cells and gray cells having the same form (size and shape), one area can be rotated or mirror of the opposite area, an area could have a number indicates the number of cells of that color in the block.

I'm looking for help in choosing a data structure and forming an algorithm to automatically generate solvable puzzles for this game.

I am implementing using JavaScript and Here's the approach I'm currently considering:

- Start with a blank 2-dimensional matrix with the desired size.
- Choose a random area size for the white area, between 2 and half of the board size (rounded down to the nearest even number), where cells that form the area is available and not taken
- Check if a matched opposite area can be acquired on the board with the same shape & size.
- If not: check if there is a space for a rotated or mirrored area.
- If not: return to step 2
- If yes: recheck the whole board for violations (mainly if there is a surrounded odd-size block left
- If there is a violation: go back to step 2
- mark the cells of the block (of 2 areas) as taken
- go to step 2 till board is filled

As for the data-structure I thought of using graph but I couldn't wrap it around my head. maybe deal with areas as it is as 2-dim matrix?

I'm not sure if this approach is optimal or if there are better data structures and algorithms to use. What data structure and algorithm would you recommend for generating solvable puzzles for this board game? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "go to step 2 till board is filled"  In the example shown, the board is not filled.  It will be extremely hard to find a valid puzzle that fills the board.  Suggest stopping when a small number of blocks ( 3 perhaps? ) of blocks have been generated.

Comment: Yes you have a point @ravenspoint 
I'm planning to make the blocks easier and smaller everytime a block is generated.. so in the last there will be few available space which will be filled with region of 2-cells (gray-white)

Answer (score 0):

I would go like:

- 2 d XxY array of `cell`s:

  ```js
      let cell = {
          x: Number, // just for passing them down easier, I assign coords too
          y: Number,
          color: "white" | "black",
          number: null | Number,
          top: true | false,
          bottom: true | false,
          left: true | false,
          right: true | false,
          taken: false, // | true
          block: []
      }
  ```
- run and extract every block (its coordinates in array)

  ```js
  function take(cell, cellFor) {
      cell.taken = true
      if (!cell.top)    take(cells[cell.y-1][cell.x], cellFor)
      if (!cell.bottom) take(cells[cell.y+1][cell.x], cellFor)
      if (!cell.left)   take(cells[cell.y][cell.x - 1], cellFor)
      if (!cell.right)  take(cells[cell.y][cell.x + 1], cellFor)
  }

  for (let row of cells)
      for (let cell of row)
          if (!cell.taken) take(cell, cell)
  ```

the shortest code I could think of.
let say you have 2x2 and `[(0,0),(1,0)]` as block.

- `take(cell[0][0])`:

  - take `(1,0)` to `(0,0)`'s block because its `.right` is `false`
  - don't add `(1,0)` because its `.bottom` is `true`
- don't `take(cell[0][1])` because when `(0,0)` was running, it took `(0,1)` for its block
- `take(cell[0][1])` ...

I think you see the pattern. To be honest there can be bugs, I haven't tried. its just a concept. also needs to be fine tuned for array length checks and other boring stuff.
`cellFor` argument is used for having a reference to the cell who have started the `take` sequence.

You have to "parse" it as `cells.flat().filter(bock=>block.length)`.

notice I didn't use the `.number` and `.color`. Once you have the blocks, you can check it with the cells in your block.
this `take` style is for creating blocks. I basically give a minimalist way to extract blocks.
Took some time but if my algo has a flaw, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I would tackle this the other way around.

- Generate a collection of blocks with different numbers, shapes and sizes.
- Select at random a small set of blocks from the collection
- Arrange the selected blocks at random, but avoiding overlap, in a board.
- Fill in the unused parts of the board with random white and grey squares.

Note that the last step may produce a puzzle that has more than one correct answer.  If you do not want that, you will have replace the last step with a more careful filling in of unused parts.